# What to use instead of charAt for arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, char

This code is to get the occurrence of the characters in the Arraylist `firlast` but charAt can't be used and gives an error

`The method charAt(int) is undefined for the type ArrayList<String>Java(67108964)`

```
int len = firlast.size();
                int count[] = new int[256];

                for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                    count[firlast.charAt(i)]++;
                
                char ch[] = new char[firlast.size()];
                for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    ch[i] = firlast.charAt(i);
                    int find = 0;
                    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                        if (firlast.charAt(i) == ch[j])
                            find++;
                    }

                    if (find == 1)
                        System.out.println("occurence " + firstlast.charAt(i) + count[firstlast.charAt(i)]);
                }
```

Output of the `firlast` array is `[rj, yf, rC, ac, ps, ni, er, et, FT, ei]`

I dont know what i did wrong. please point out where i did wrong.

Comment: If `firlast` is an `ArrayList` as stated in the introduction, then `firlast.charAt(i)` won't compile. Are you sure that this is the exact code you are executing? - If not, please refer to 'How to create a [mcve]?'.

Comment: Yes this is the code. i wrote this code in a text file and compile in the cmd. just to try without intellisense. now i tried it with the VS code and now this `The method charAt(int) is undefined for the type ArrayList<String>Java(67108964)`

Answer (score 2):

There is no `charAt` method on an `ArrayList`.  The closest is `List.get(int)` which returns the list element at a given position.

However, in your example you have an `ArrayList<String>`, so `get` will return a `String` rather than a character, and you can't use a string as an array index.

Unfortunately, I think the real problem here is that `ArrayList<String>` is the wrong data structure for this code.  Better alternatives might be `char[]`, `ArrayList<Character>` `String` or `StringBuilder`.  It is hard to say without more context.

Comment: I changed arraylist to char[] and now it works i get the desired output thanks for clarification @Stephen